# Geopandas: uniting land masses and coastal buffer polygons

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I want to unite the polygons I create via the `gpd.buffer()` method from a coastline shapefile with the polygons of land masses
Both datasets (coasts and land) are retrieved from [www.naturalearthdata.com](http://www.naturalearthdata.com).

```sh
$ wget https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_coastline.zip
$ unzip ne_50m_coastline.zip -d coastlines
$ wget https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_land.zip
$ unzip ne_50m_land.zip -d land
```

My workflow so far:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coast_shapefile = "coastlines/ne_50m_coastline.shp"
land_shapefile = "land/ne_10m_land.shp"
# read shapefiles with geopandas and specify the initial CRS (units: degree)
coast = gpd.read_file(coast_shapefile, crs={'init' :'epsg:4326'})
land = gpd.read_file(land_shapefile, crs={'init' :'epsg:4326'})
# now create a buffer zone around the coastlines
coast_bfr = gdf.geometry.buffer(0.2)
```

The buffer (`coast_bfr`) represents polygons around the coastlines and "leave an empty area" in the inner of the land masses. I would now like to combine these buffer polygons with the polygons representing the land masses. However, geopandas' `union()` doesn't work.

Any hints how I can achieve this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated the `gdf.overlay()` capabilities? Union (well, cascaded_union and unary_union) are element-wise operations handled by `shapely`, but the whole set of shapes is operated upon by the [overlay operations](https://geopandas.org/set_operations.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, aorr. I tried this as well, yes. The process takes pretty long and the result is equal to whatever I specify as a first argument in `overlay()`.
For example, plotting the union of `coast_bfr` and `land`, which I retrieve via
`unite = gpd.overlay(coast_bfr, land, how='union')`, results in the same plot as from `coast_bfr`. Seems like the polygons from `land` are ignored.

Comment: Are you sure they're the same? How did you check? `len(coast_bfr)==len(unite)` is `True`? I'd be surprised if that's the case, but if it is the case then it's more likely that one of your input layers is empty or that they don't actually intersect than it is that there's an issue with `overlay`. It might be time to start learning the `gdf.plot()` api so that you can explore your data easier and share more information about the layers you're feeding in and creating. It might be useful to add a few images to your question, or to start with smaller files so you can iterate and try things faster.